# ValueError: expected dense_22 to have shape (None, 37) but got array with shape (1000, 2)

Tags: keras, lstm, nlp-question-answering

I am currently working on a question answering system. I create a synthetic dataset that contains multiple words in the answers. But, the answers are not a span of the given context.

Initially, I am planning to test it using a deep learning-based model. But I have some problems building the model.
This is how I vectorized data.

```
def vectorize(data, word2idx, story_maxlen, question_maxlen, answer_maxlen):
    """ Create the story and question vectors and the label """
    Xs, Xq, Y = [], [], []
    for story, question, answer in data:
        xs = [word2idx[word] for word in story]
        xq = [word2idx[word] for word in question]
        y = [word2idx[word] for word in answer]
        #y = np.zeros(len(word2idx) + 1)
        #y[word2idx[answer]] = 1
        Xs.append(xs)
        Xq.append(xq)
        Y.append(y)
    return (pad_sequences(Xs, maxlen=story_maxlen), 
            pad_sequences(Xq, maxlen=question_maxlen),
            pad_sequences(Y, maxlen=answer_maxlen))
            #np.array(Y))
```

below is how I create the model.

```
    # story encoder. Output dim: (None, story_maxlen, EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE)
story_encoder = Sequential()
story_encoder.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, 
                              output_dim=EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE,
                              input_length=story_maxlen))
story_encoder.add(Dropout(0.3))

# question encoder. Output dim: (None, question_maxlen, EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE)
question_encoder = Sequential()
question_encoder.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
                               output_dim=EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE,
                               input_length=question_maxlen))
question_encoder.add(Dropout(0.3))

# episodic memory (facts): story * question
# Output dim: (None, question_maxlen, story_maxlen)
facts_encoder = Sequential()

facts_encoder.add(Merge([story_encoder, question_encoder], 
                        mode="dot", dot_axes=[2, 2]))
facts_encoder.add(Permute((2, 1)))                        

## combine response and question vectors and do logistic regression
answer = Sequential()
answer.add(Merge([facts_encoder, question_encoder], 
                 mode="concat", concat_axis=-1))
answer.add(LSTM(LSTM_OUTPUT_SIZE, return_sequences=True))
answer.add(Dropout(0.3))
answer.add(Flatten())
answer.add(Dense(vocab_size,activation= "softmax"))


answer.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy",
               metrics=["accuracy"])

answer.fit([Xs_train, Xq_train], Y_train, 
           batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, nb_epoch=NBR_EPOCHS,
           validation_data=([Xs_test, Xq_test], Y_test))
```

and this is the summary of the model

```
   _________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
merge_46 (Merge)             (None, 5, 616)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_23 (LSTM)               (None, 5, 32)             83072     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_69 (Dropout)         (None, 5, 32)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_9 (Flatten)          (None, 160)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)             (None, 37)                5957      
=================================================================
Total params: 93,765.0
Trainable params: 93,765.0
Non-trainable params: 0.0
_________________________________________________________________
```

It gives the following error.

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_22 to have shape (None, 37) but got array with shape (1000, 2)
```

I think the error is related to Y_train, Y_test. I should encode them to categorical values and the answers are not spans of text, but sequential. I don't know what/how to do it.
how can I fix it? any ideas?

EDIT:

When I use sparse_categorical_crossentropy in the loss, and Reshape(2,-1);
answer.summary()

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
merge_94 (Merge)             (None, 5, 616)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_65 (LSTM)               (None, 5, 32)             83072     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_139 (Dropout)        (None, 5, 32)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_22 (Reshape)         (None, 2, 80)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_44 (Dense)             (None, 2, 37)             2997      
=================================================================
Total params: 90,805.0
Trainable params: 90,805.0
Non-trainable params: 0.0
_________________________________________________________________
```

EDIT2:
The model after modifications

```
# story encoder. Output dim: (None, story_maxlen, EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE)
story_encoder = Sequential()
story_encoder.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, 
                              output_dim=EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE,
                              input_length=story_maxlen))
story_encoder.add(Dropout(0.3))

# question encoder. Output dim: (None, question_maxlen, EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE)
question_encoder = Sequential()
question_encoder.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
                               output_dim=EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE,
                               input_length=question_maxlen))
question_encoder.add(Dropout(0.3))

# episodic memory (facts): story * question
# Output dim: (None, question_maxlen, story_maxlen)
facts_encoder = Sequential()

facts_encoder.add(Merge([story_encoder, question_encoder], 
                        mode="dot", dot_axes=[2, 2]))
facts_encoder.add(Permute((2, 1)))                        

## combine response and question vectors and do logistic regression
## combine response and question vectors and do logistic regression
answer = Sequential()
answer.add(Merge([facts_encoder, question_encoder], 
                 mode="concat", concat_axis=-1))
answer.add(LSTM(LSTM_OUTPUT_SIZE, return_sequences=True))
answer.add(Dropout(0.3))
#answer.add(Flatten())
answer.add(keras.layers.Reshape((2, -1)))    
answer.add(Dense(vocab_size,activation= "softmax"))

answer.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
               metrics=["accuracy"])

answer.fit([Xs_train, Xq_train], Y_train, 
           batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, nb_epoch=NBR_EPOCHS,
           validation_data=([Xs_test, Xq_test], Y_test))
```

It still gives

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_46 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand - Y_train, Y_test comprise of indexes (not one-hot vectors). If so - change loss to sparse_categorical_entropy:

```
answer.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
               metrics=["accuracy"])
```

As far as I understand - Y_train, Y_test have a sequence dimension. And the length of questions (5) doesn't equal to the length of the answers (2). This dimension is removed by `Flatten()`. Try to replace `Flatten()` by `Reshape()`:

```
# answer.add(Flatten())
answer.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((2, -1)))
```

Comment: when i change the loss function, i get the ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_22 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (1000, 2).  There are 1000 samples in the test, and each answer contains 2 words at most. @Andrey

Comment: Thank you @Andrey. Once i remove Flatten() layer, add Reshape(2,-1); it gives ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_33 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 2).                                       
vocab_size= 37
story_maxlen= 552 question_maxlen= 5
answer_maxlen= 2
story--> (1000, 552)  question--> (1000, 5) answer shape--> (1000, 2)

Comment: I updated the question and add answer.summary() after these modifications. @Andrey

Comment: @programming123 have you changed loss to sparse_categorical_entropy ?